# Google Cloud Spring Streams Creates Multiple Threads for One Message

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to create a consumer for Google Pub/Sub using Spring Cloud Streams. I have the following `Consumer<T>`

MyConsumer.java

```
@Service
public class MyConsumer implements Consumer<StorageObjectMessage> {

    @Override
    public void accept(StorageObjectMessage message) {
        
        log.log(Level.FINE, "Consumed new message with id of {0}", message.getId());
        log.log(Level.FINEST, "Contents of message: {0}", message);
        
        if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(validateMessage(message))) {
            
            try {
                
                processMessage(message);
                log.log(Level.INFO, "Completed processing of new message with id of {0}", message.getId());
                
            } catch(Exception e) {
                
                log.log(Level.WARNING, "Error while processing message with id of {0}", message.getId() + ": " + e.getMessage());
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }

}
```

application.yaml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gcp:
      pubsub:
        publisher:
          executor-threads: 8
        subscriber:
          max-ack-extension-period: 1800
    function:
      definition: myConsumer;
    stream:
      poller:
        fixedDelay: 10
      bindings:
        myConsumer-in-0:
          destination: kirk-us-east4-my-topic
          group: kirk-us-east4-my-topic-subscriber-group
```

I then place one (and only one) message conforming to StorageObjectMessage to the topic, but despite the fact that only one message is sent the binder starts up a multiple threads, causing the message to be processed more than once.

logs

```
2024-02-21T21:16:43.394Z  INFO 1 --- [sub-subscriber1] c.h.m.s.m.MyConsumer  : Consumed new message with id of kirk-us-east4-my-bucket/update/inbound/upd_20231024204504-00018.xml/1708550202277752
2024-02-21T21:16:43.402Z  INFO 1 --- [sub-subscriber2] c.h.m.s.m.MyConsumer  : Consumed new message with id of kirk-us-east4-my-bucket/update/inbound/upd_20231024204504-00018.xml/1708550202277752
2024-02-21T21:16:44.844Z  INFO 1 --- [sub-subscriber4] c.h.m.s.m.MyConsumer  : Consumed new message with ID of kirk-us-east4-my-bucket/update/inbound/upd_20231024204504-00018.xml/1708550202277752
```